# How to access state during transitions in Akka FSM

Tags: scala, transition, akka, fsm, state-machine

I am using Akka FSM for handling state in my Actor. I want some actions to be performed every time a transition to a certain state occurs, no matter which state the transition was made from. After reading the docs, I felt certain that this could be resolved like this:

```
onTransition({
  case (_, ToState) => performAction(stateData)
})

...

when(FromState){
  case "changestate" => goto(ToState) using NewStateData
}
```

However, when the transition occurs, stateData is not yet updated to NewStateData.

What is the recommended way to perform actions on entering a certain state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to my attention, that was indeed an oversight, which I fixed immediately (see [the ticket](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/1414-fsm--make-next-state-data-accessible-from-ontransition-blocks)). Unfortunately there is not much you can do (apart from merging in the tiny patch yourself) until 1.3 is out, which should be next week; if you are particularly impatient, I would appreciate if you could try out RC2 with the fix which will be released this week.

Comment: it took two days longer, but RC2 is out now.

Comment: I appear to have come across this problem in akka 2.3.12. Can you confirm whether new state set using `using` is available in the respective case of the partial function passed to `onTransition()`?

Comment: It should be available as `nextStateData`.

Comment: Looking at the Javadoc at https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4/index.html, it looks like `nextStateData` is static.  Maybe there is some scala magic that happens, but that is concerning at the least.  Does that method work from Java, especially if you have multiple FSM actors?